# 32-bit program using Office IFilters when 64-bit Office is installed

Tags: 64-bit, microsoft-office, 32-bit

64-bit Office installs 64-bit IFilters for its document types, but does not install 32-bit IFilters. Therefore, 32-bit programs that rely on IFilters cannot work with 64-bit Office. And although there is an option to download 32-bit IFilters from Microsoft, the installer will not run on a 64-bit machine, complaining about architecture mismatch.

Is there any way to make 32-bit programs extract text from Office documents using IFilters when 64-bit Office is installed?

Thanks.

Comment: This is probably why [Microsoft recommends the 32-bit version of Office](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/choose-the-32-bit-or-64-bit-version-of-microsoft-office-HA010369476.aspx) even on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: @WilliamJackson: That should be an answer.

Comment: I ended up writing a stub process that marshals IFilter requests from 32-bit to 64-bit, and the results back. There does't seem to be a simpler way.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem - I have a 32bit app which I run on a Win 7 64 bit Machine.

My App, uses iFilters to extract text from files - .doc and .docx

I am not sure if this will work for you, but my workaround is to:

`Regedit` - Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.doc\PersistentHandler` and then copy the registry key.  (MAKE SURE YOU SAVE THIS FOR ANY ROLL-BACK IF REQUIRED)

`Regedit` - Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.docx\PersistentHandler` and paste the .doc PersistentHandler key over the .docx PersistentHandler.

This essentially tells it to point .docx files at the  `offfilt.dll` (`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\offfilt.dll` (x86))

I am sure that technially someone will tell me what I am doing is completely wrong, but it works for me!

I have a batch file I run which switches the registry from the original to the .doc settings and back again as required.

I assume if you are trying to go the other way - 32bit to 64 you can reverse the process.

Answer (score 0):

**No**. [According to Microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/choose-the-32-bit-or-64-bit-version-of-microsoft-office-HA010369476.aspx):

> By default, Microsoft Office 2010 installs the 32-bit version of Office 2010 even if your computer is running 64-bit editions of Windows.
>
> The 32-bit version of Office 2010 is the recommended option for most people, because it prevents potential compatibility issues with other 32-bit applications, specifically third-party add-ins that are available only for 32-bit operating systems.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I asked about Office IFilters, not Office. (You can install and use Office IFilters without installing Office.) And, oddly enough, the 32-bit installation of Office will in fact always install 64-bit IFilters on 64-bit Windows.